# How to track the unordered pairs in the `pandas` dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `pd.Dataframe` with the columns `R_fighter` - the name of the first fighter, `B_fighter` - the name of the second fighter and the `Winner` column. Data is sorted in chronological order and I would like to add a column, where if the fighters have previously met and the `R` fighter won to set value to `-1`, if the `B` fighter won - `1`, and `0` otherwise. If it was guaranteed, that the fighters can meet again in the same order (`R_fighter` is again `R_fighter`, `B_fighter` is again `B_fighter`), then one can do the following:

```
last_winner_col = np.zeros(df_train.shape[0])

for x in df_train.groupby(['R_fighter', 'B_fighter'])['Winner']:
    last_winner = 0
    for idx, val in zip(x[1].index, x[1].values):
        last_winner_col[idx] = last_winner
        last_winner = 2 * val - 1
```

And add the resulting `pd.Series` to the dataset. However, their role may change in the consequent fight. The solution, which come to my mind are very lengthy and cumbersome. I would be grateful, if one suggested a handy way to track the previous winner to take into account the possibility of the change of fighters order?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "sorted" version of your two combatants and use that:

```
import pandas as pd

a = list("ABCDEFGH1234")
b = list("12341234ABCD")
win = list("ABCD12341234")

df = pd.DataFrame({"R_fighter":a, "B_fighter":b, "Winner":win})

# make a column with fixed order
df["combatants"] = df[['R_fighter', 'B_fighter']].apply(lambda x: sorted(x), axis=1)

# or simply set the result
df["w"] = df[['R_fighter', 'B_fighter', 'Winner']].apply(lambda x: '-1' 
                                                         if x[2]==x[0] 
                                                         else ('1' if x[2]==x[1] 
                                                               else '0'), axis=1 )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   R_fighter    B_fighter     Winner    combatants      w
0          A            1          A        [1, A]     -1
1          B            2          B        [2, B]     -1
2          C            3          C        [3, C]     -1
3          D            4          D        [4, D]     -1
4          E            1          1        [1, E]      1
5          F            2          2        [2, F]      1
6          G            3          3        [3, G]      1
7          H            4          4        [4, H]      1
8          1            A          1        [1, A]     -1
9          2            B          2        [2, B]     -1
10         3            C          3        [3, C]     -1
11         4            D          4        [4, D]     -1
```

To get the winner based on `'combatants'` (wich contains the sorted names) you can do:

```
df["w_combatants"] = df[['combatants', 'Winner']].apply(lambda x: '-1' 
                                                        if x[1]==x[0][0] 
                                                        else ('1' if x[1]==x[0][1] 
                                                                  else '0'), axis=1 )
```

to get

```
   R_fighter    B_fighter    Winner    combatants      w    w_combatants
0          A            1         A        [1, A]     -1               1
1          B            2         B        [2, B]     -1               1
2          C            3         C        [3, C]     -1               1
3          D            4         D        [4, D]     -1               1
4          E            1         1        [1, E]      1              -1
5          F            2         2        [2, F]      1              -1
6          G            3         3        [3, G]      1              -1
7          H            4         4        [4, H]      1              -1
8          1            A         1        [1, A]     -1              -1
9          2            B         2        [2, B]     -1              -1
10         3            C         3        [3, C]     -1              -1
11         4            D         4        [4, D]     -1              -1
```

Answer (score 0):

On the grounds of @Patrick Artner answer, I've come up with the following solution:

```
df_train[['fighters']] = df_train[['R_fighter', 'B_fighter']].apply(lambda x :tuple(sorted(x)), axis = 1)
df_train[['fighter_ord_changed']] = df_train[['R_fighter', 'B_fighter']].apply(lambda x : np.argsort(x)[0], axis = 1)

last_winner_col = np.zeros(df_train.shape[0])

for x in df_train.groupby('fighters')['Winner']:
    last_winner = 0
    for idx, val in zip(x[1].index, x[1].values):
        flag = df_train['fighter_ord_changed'][idx]
        last_winner_col[idx] = -last_winner if flag else last_winner
        last_winner = 2 * (val ^ flag) - 1
```